# Installing Datastax Cassandra

Tags: cassandra-2.1

I am trying to install the Datastax Community Edition on my Windows Machine. But my cassandra server is not able to start.
It shows the following message:
Detected powershell execution permissions.  Running with enhanced startup scripts. Setting up Cassandra environment *---------------------------------------------------------------------* *---------------------------------------------------------------------*      WARNING!  Automatic page file configuration detected.     It is recommended that you disable swap when running Cassandra     for performance and stability reasons.  *---------------------------------------------------------------------* *---------------------------------------------------------------------* Cassandra port already in use (storage_port: 7000 ).  Aborting

Answer (score 1):

Did you install the Windows service? Search under "Control Panel > Administrative Tools > View local services" for items starting with DataStax, there should be 1 for Cassandra plus another 2 if you have OpsCenter and the DataStax agent installed. Based on the error message I'd suspect it's already running in the background.

The warning around swap being enabled you can probably ignore if you just run it on your local machine. It would be good if you could provide more details around how you're trying to start it and which version of Windows you're using.